# Change the order of the address and publisher in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I need to change the order of the fields in my bibliography. Currently, any entry for a book I have is displayed as:

City: Publisher.

I want to change it to

Publisher: City.

Given a tex file as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, firstinits=true, maxbibnames=99, minbibnames=1, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}

hello world \cite{Ab_Steg}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the .bib file as follows:

```
@BOOK{Ab_Steg,
 author = "M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun",
 title = {Handbook of mathematical functions},
 publisher = "Dover publications",
 year = "1965",
 language="English",
 address="New York"
 }
```

The result is:

[image]

I want the position of "Dover publications" and "New York" to switch.

Comment: What biblatex style do you use?

Comment: A self-contained [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be *really* helpful here. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I am using numeric.

Comment: Added the exampple.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. Is there a background behind this request? Are there any circumstances when this "backwards style" is correct?

Comment: My supervisor requested this formatting for books in my bibliography. I'm not entirely sure why, though. I think it is confusing since conferences are tied to a location, but for books, the publisher is more important than the location.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Insert this after loading biblatex:

```
% let "publisher" and "location" change place
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

This is from `standard.bbx` in Biblatex, with only those two interchanged.

If only `book`s should be affected, a straightforward method is to not change the macro as above, but instead define a new one, `\newbibmacro{location+publisher+date}` with the definition as above. And then you copy the whole `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}` part from `standard.bbx` into your file, but exchange the `\usebibmacro` call to use the alternative macro instead.

Comment: Do you mean after the \usepackage{biblatex} command? Thanks, this works perfectly! Next time I will have a look at standard.bbx.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict this change to only references that are books, not conferences as well?

Comment: I don't know how to best do that, but I've added a rather dumb but straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `\ifentrytype{book}` to change the macro only for `@books`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {\printlist{publisher}%
     \iflistundef{location}
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
       {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
     \printlist{location}}
    {\printlist{location}%
     \iflistundef{publisher}
      {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
     \printlist{publisher}}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, firstinits=true, maxbibnames=99, minbibnames=1, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {\printlist{publisher}%
     \iflistundef{location}
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
       {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
     \printlist{location}}
    {\printlist{location}%
     \iflistundef{publisher}
      {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
     \printlist{publisher}}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{cicero,wilde}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]