# References linked to website by click

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing, urls

I am new to LaTeX and I have the problem about linking the references to the available papers in the internet. I have loaded these packages

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-ibid,citestyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
```

I will get a bibliography in the thesis and the urls are shown. However, I am only interested in linking the references in the bibliography to the urls, I don't want them to be shown. This should be done by clicking on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to keep the link while hiding the URL is to set your URL in the corresponding entry in the .bib file like this:

```
note = {\href{http://www.something.com}{View online}}
```

instead of this

```
url = {http://www.something.com}
```

But it won't create a link over the whole entry.

**EDIT:** minimal example

.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-ibid,citestyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\bibliography{biblio}

\begin{document}
Texttexttext \cite{ref1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@Article{ref1,
author = {Chuck Norris},
title = {About bibtex},
journal = {Journal},
year = {1999},
note = {\href{http://www.something.com}{View online}}
}
```

Comment: good idea, however it does not work in my file. if i add it in the normal .tex file it is shown, but if it is in the .bib it completly breaks down.

Furthermore, i am more interested in linking the whole entry to some url, even if your idea would be a nice compromise

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. Would you like a minimal example?

Comment: would be nice if you could give on, it is maybe because of my used settings in the biblatex package?

Comment: Here it is. I used the settings you provided for the package so that's not the problem.

Comment: yes it works, now i have to understand why my file does not want to do so^^

Comment: really crazy if i add my bibilography to your short .tex example it works, however not with the my .tex

Comment: Do you have any other packages which could change the bibliography settings, or induce some kind of conflicts?

Comment: i found the flaw, i copy pasted a # in the end of one url, this crashed the whole file. Thanks a lot John, you were a great help to me

Comment: one very last question, note is now in some cases bevor the journal, how can a ban them always to the end of the reference:
++++++++++++++++ 
Blanchard, Olivier and Roberto Perotti (2002). An Empirical Characteri-
zation of the Dynamic Eects of Changes in Government Spending and
Taxes on Output. Tech. rep. **View online**. The Quarterly Journal of Economics.
+++++++++++++
to 
++
Blanchard, Olivier and Roberto Perotti (2002). An Empirical Characteri-
zation of the Dynamic Eects of Changes in Government Spending and
Taxes on Output. Tech. rep. The Quarterly Journal of Economics. **View online**.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked =) To put note in the end, I did not try but there is something to do with the bibliography style options. You should find an answer there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168077/change-the-order-of-the-address-and-publisher-in-biblatex?rq=1
Otherwise it could be interesting to ask another question about this point