# Revisiting: "Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries"

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I am trying to achieve citations and a bibliography, that look like this:

> There’s a sentence, where a book of SCOTT (1991) is quoted. Then some
>   text with STRATTON et al. 1981 in it.
>
> #### Bibliography
>
> SCOTT 1991: David A. Scott, Metallography and microstructure of
>   ancient and historic metals, Los Angeles, 1991.
>
> STRATTON et al. 1981: Carol Stratton und Miriam McNair Scott, The Art
>   of Sukhothai. Thailand’s Golden Age, Oxford, New York, Melbourne,
>   1981.

With lockstep's solution of the original question ["Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries) I got pretty close, but the uppercase letters and "et al." are not going well together.
This is what I got so far:

```
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}
@book{Scott1991,
address = {Los Angeles},
author = {Scott, David A.},
publisher = {Archetype Books},
title = {{Metallography and microstructure of ancient and historic metals}},
year = {1991}
}

@book{Stratton1981,
address = {Oxford, New York, Melbourne},
author = {Stratton, Carol and {McNair Scott}, Miriam},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
title = {{The Art of Sukhothai. Thailand's Golden Age}},
year = {1981}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[%
    citestyle=authoryear-comp,%
    bibstyle=authortitle-comp,%
    backend=bibtex]{biblatex}%  
    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
        maxcitenames=1,%
        language=ngerman,%  
        punctfont=true,%
        autopunct=false,%
        sorting=nyt}

% -- Publisher, Location, Date
        \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
        \printlist{location}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{date}%
        \newunit}

% -- Author-Year-Block at the beginning

    \newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
    \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
    }

    \renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
        \printtext[]{%          
            \begingroup
                \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
                \printnames{labelname}%
                \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
            \endgroup
            }%
        \addcolon\addspace
    }
% -- Sorting, dots etc.

    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
%   \DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}   % <--- Produces labels in Uppercase but also kills "et al."

    \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\isdot}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{parens}{#1} 
    \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1\isdot}

    \DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

    \renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
    \setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}


\bibliography{Test.bib}     

\begin{document}
There's a sentence, where a book of \textcite{Scott1991} is quoted. Then some text with \cite{Stratton1981} in it.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'd love to be enlightened by you, magically producing uppercase names and lowercase "et al.". :)

^1 borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168077/change-the-order-of-the-address-and-publisher-in-biblatex)

Comment: Note that you are missing some `%`s in your code at the end of lines, this can potentially introduce unwanted space. There should be no need to redefine `\newblockpunct` if you already have `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`. And you should probably use `andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}` to not mess up the punctuation tracker. With `biblatex` >= 3.3 `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}` would be `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}`. `\DeclareFieldFormat{parens}{#1}` looks a bit suspicious to me, too.

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article, book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, patent, thesis, unpublished, misc]{title}{#1\isdot} ` can easily be replaced by `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\isdot} ` to reset the title format for *all* types.

Comment: I tried that last part before posting the question but it did not produce the same result. I could not figure out why.

Comment: It does the same in your MWE, I would be interested to see an example of how it doesn't work. It should really.

Comment: I'll eliminate it from the example. But my original document is huge and I do not yet know how to reproduce that in a smaller scale. There are a few other oddities like that but I thought I should not cutter the question...

Comment: That is good thinking (we prefer one question at a time). But if you can find the time to isolate the issue a bit, do not hesitate to ask a new question.

Comment: I found out that I need both redefinitions, \newblockpunct and \newunitpunct. Otherwise I either get dots between the parts of the entries or a new line for each part. Where Do I need to put the %? These always are a mystery to me....

Comment: That could be because of your `block=nbpar`, just drop it. For `%` placement read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) and linked questions (especially [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40948/35864)), you basically want it at all line ends except after a command without braces. So after `\foo` it is not necessary, but after `\foo{` or `\foo{bar}` you would need a `%`. Cf. also the modified version of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}` to the `\renewbibmacro*{begentry}` bit and to `\AtEveryCite`

```
\AtEveryCite{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext{%
    \begingroup
      \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
      \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \addcolon\addspace
}
```

In pre-3.3 `biblatex` that would be `\mkbibnamelast` instead.

---

Or you can go about this the other way and make `\textsc` the default and change the font only after the bibliography label.

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext{%
    \begingroup
      \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \addcolon\addspace
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{##1}%
}
```

Comment: wow, that was fast! This is producing small caps, but I need the real uppercase letters. I should affect both, the citation and the bibliography. I will update the question to point that out, too.

Comment: @fortunecookies Well, just replace `\textsc` by `\MakeUppercase` if you must. Can you specify where exactly you need the CAPS? When you say bibliography do you mean in the labels and in the actual entry?

Comment: My university just wants them to look like that. Personally I'd also prefer small caps. With bibliography I meant it to look like my example on top: Uppercase labels and normal names in the actual entry.

Comment: @fortunecookies OK, check out the edited answer (but replace `\textsc` with `\MakeUppercase`).

Comment: I chose the first option and it works great. just one last tweak: there should be an empty line between the entries of the bibliography: I guess my lack of % produced it accidentally but how do I get it on purpose?

Comment: @fortunecookies Modify `\bibitemsep`, maybe `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{2\itemsep}`, `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\parsep}` or `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}` are what you are after.

Comment: the baselineskip fitted nicely. Is it ok to kill the hanging indentation with 
`\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}`?

Comment: @fortunecookies If you (or your university) insist on having no hanging indent. I suppose you can get away with it if the `\bibitemsep` is large enough, otherwise it will look a bit meh.

Comment: I definitely see what you mean, but I am bound by their citation guidelines. Thanks a lot for helping me out so patiently!

Comment: @moeve There is a tiny problem remaining... when I use ´\fullcite´ or ´\footfullcite´ to display the full bibliographic information of a book, then both names (in the label and in the actual entry) are in uppercase letters. How do I only change the labeling part?

Comment: @fortunecookies Can you try the alternative solution?

Comment: @moeve The `\fullcite`-problem appears only when using the first solution. The second one looks good. :)