# BibLaTeX: How can I remove the comma after "school" in @thesis entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex

I want to remove the comma between the "school" field and the date (year) in an @thesis bibliography entry:

[image]

Here is my minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = numeric]{biblatex}

%%%%%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492917

\newtoggle{bbx:datemissing}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{\toggletrue{bbx:datemissing}%}

\renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \toggletrue{bbx:datemissing}%
  \iffieldundef{issue}{}{
    \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{issue}}}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{date:print}{%
  \togglefalse{bbx:datemissing}%
  \printdate}

\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date:print}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date:print}%
  \newunit}

%%%%%%%%

%%% This is what I came up with
\renewbibmacro{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{institution}{%
    \setunit*{\space}%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  }%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
  @thesis {mythesis,
    author = {Me, I.},
    school = {University},
    title = {Sometitle},
    type = {Phd thesis},
    year = {123}
  }  
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
\nocite{*}
```

I already tried `\renewbibmacro{institution+location+date}{...}`, but that did not work. I am quite new to BibLaTeX.

My thought was that the `numeric` style uses the entry types from `standard`, which is from where I copied the macro and removed all commas. However, that clearly did not work. How can I remove this comma?

Comment: Did you delete your aux files and recompile? The code here produces no comma.

Comment: @AlanMunn That's odd, I must have missed something when creating the minimal example because it clearly does not work in my full code.

Comment: @AlanMunn I have added some code I copied from a different question.

Comment: (That only adds a dot, not a comma...)

Comment: The code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491895/35864 you are using explicitly shifts the date printing away from `\usebibmacro{date}` to `\usebibmacro{date:print}`. That is done in a very unsophisticated fashion and for all entry types alike. The date is now printed after the `pages` field. Since the punctuation before a field is always the *last* punctuation command the style issued before the field is printed, it is not enough to modify `institution+location+date` as the punctuation commands that are relevant come in later. ...

Comment: ... Depending on what exactly you want to achieve it may be better to try and find a more sophisticated answer to moving around the year w.r.t. the `pages` field.

Comment: Off-topic but I would definitely replace `\usepackage{ngerman}` with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. `ngerman.sty` hasn't been updated since 1999. `babel`'s `german` module is actively maintained and actually works together with packages like `biblatex`, `csquotes` and a host of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `\nopunct` just before the `\newunit` of your redefined `institution+location+date` macro. I've changed the document class of your example to `article`. Despite its name, the `minimal` document class should *not* be used for MWEs since it is in fact too minimal. I've also removed the `filecontents` package, which is now part of the LaTeX kernel.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = numeric]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bbx:datemissing}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{\toggletrue{bbx:datemissing}}

\renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \toggletrue{bbx:datemissing}%
  \iffieldundef{issue}{}{
    \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{issue}}}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{date:print}{%
  \togglefalse{bbx:datemissing}%
  \printdate}

\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date:print}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date:print}%
  \newunit}
%%% This is what I came up with
\renewbibmacro{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{institution}{%
    \setunit*{\space}%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\space}%
  }%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \nopunct\newunit%
}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
  @thesis {mythesis,
    author = {Me, I.},
    school = {University of Somewhere},
    title = {Sometitle},
    type = {Phd thesis},
    year = {1980}
  }  
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That works. But why do I have to put `\nopuct` after `\usebibmacro{date}`? I would have expected it to go before... Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @HerpDerpington The way punctuation is added in `biblatex` is quite complex, and it happens asynchronously. So (roughly) the punctuation isn't produced where it's called.  See §4.11.7 of the `biblatex` manual for a detailed explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to [Change the order of the pages and year in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491895/35864), whose code you are using, uses quite blunt instruments to move the `date` printing after `pages`. This may not be exactly what you want or need in all situations.

Here is a slightly more complex setup that moves the date only if there are `pages` (or a `chapter`), which may result in an output that works slightly better for you in some situations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bbx:datesuppressed}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{pages}}
    and test {\iffieldundef{chapter}}}
    {\printdate}
    {\toggletrue{bbx:datesuppressed}}}

\renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \toggletrue{bbx:datesuppressed}%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{issue}}}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{date:print}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:datesuppressed}
    {\togglefalse{bbx:datesuppressed}%
     \printdate}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date:print}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date:print}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{institution}
    {\setunit*{\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{mythesis,
  author = {Me, I.},
  school = {University},
  title  = {Sometitle},
  year   = {123},
}  
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{mythesis,sigfridsson,westfahl:space}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: I. Me. “Sometitle”. Phd thesis. University 123.]

As Alan explained in the comments under his answer, `biblatex`'s punctuation handling is asynchronous: Punctuation is stored in a buffer and only printed once it is needed (i.e. when the next `\print...` command actually prints something). Since in the code in the question the `\usebibmacro{date}` in `institution+location+date` doesn't actually print the date, the `\setunit` before it does not ultimately control the punctuation before the date. The date is only printed by `date:print` in  `chapter+pages`, at which point other `\setunit` commands will have added different punctuation into the buffer.

`\nopunct` sets a permanent marker not to print any punctuation until new content/text is printed by a `\print...` command. In this case it helps to suppress the undesired period. Since `\nopunct` can be used inside and outside the punctuation tracker it is a handy tool to tweak punctuation, but I generally try to avoid it and prefer solutions not using it, as it can have effects that go beyond what is desired.